# Why does my Java Window not close, when I push the close window?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I created this Java code

```
   package javaGUI;

   import javax.swing.*;  
   import java.awt.*;  
   import java.awt.event.*;  
   public class labelSwingExample extends Frame implements ActionListener{  
JTextField tf; JLabel l; JButton b;
JFrame frame;
labelSwingExample(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    tf=new JTextField("www.google.com");  
    tf.setBounds(50,50, 150,20);

    l=new JLabel();  
    l.setBounds(50,100, 250,20);      
    b=new JButton("Find IP");  
    b.setBounds(50,150,95,30);  
    b.addActionListener(this);    
    add(b);add(tf);add(l);    
    setSize(400,400);  
    setLayout(null);  
    setVisible(true);  
}  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
    try{  
    String host=tf.getText();  
    String ip=java.net.InetAddress.getByName(host).getHostAddress();  
    l.setText("IP of "+host+" is: "+ip);  
    }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}  
}  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    new labelSwingExample();  
} }
```

My Problem is now, that the windows doesn't close, when I push the close window X.
I added this example code these three lines in order to add the close funtionality
to this java swing window:

```
JFrame frame;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Please tell me why my frame commands don't work ?

Comment: ehm ... You just said they do work. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: do **not** extend a `JFrame` just to use it... do not even use a `Frame` when using Swing components (`JFrame`, `JButton`, `JPanel`, ...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jframe setDefaultCloseOperation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250434/jframe-setdefaultcloseoperation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The class should extend `JFrame` instead of `Frame`, it should look like the following:

```
public class labelSwingExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Comment: Thank you ! My code is working now

Comment: Great, could you mark it as solution so others can find it? @user12467638

Answer (score 0):

Your class extends `Frame`, you have a local variable `JFrame`, *and* have a variable `JFrame` inside your constructor.. (and you're only closing this last one).

Just let your class extend `JFrame`, and call the `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on itself, like this:

```
// Minor note: I've used an uppercase `L` for your class, which is a code standard in Java
public class LabelSwingExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  JTextField tf; JLabel l; JButton b;

  public LabelSwingExample(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

No need for any additional frames as variables, since your class itself *is* the frame.